# WFFM how to remove a "Register a Goal" save action

Tags: xdb, wffm

How can I remove the disabled "Register a Goal" save actions from a WFFM form?

For some reason, some of our Form items have this save action and I want to remove it, but cannot see how to do that. I tried turning on raw values, but I can't see the content for the "Register a Goal" action, only the markup for the email action (referring to the image below).

[image]

Comment: Register a goal is an action from :   /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/System/System Action . If you remove it from here it should not appear on your list. Please test it and I will add my answer here

Comment: Thanks, yes that does indeed remove it. I'm not sure why some of my forms were showing that save action while others were not though?

Answer (score 5):

You can remove it by deselecting it from the `Tracking` field. Switch over to the Content Editor, the `Advanced` section and then select `Goals` option from the `Tracking` field.

You can then deselect the Goals in the popup, which will mean it is no longer listed in the Save Actions.

[image: WFFM Goals]

I'm not aware of any other (easier) way of removing this, or disabling this completely unless you have `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` set to `false` (but that means you longer have the ability to use Rules Engine for form fields or in-session personalization).